# R order list by file size

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a list:

```
files <- list.files(path="new/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

Then I can find the size from:

`x <- file.info(files)`

`x[order(-x$size),]`

I don't know how to order `files`, by the info found in `file.info(files)`, in this case size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds to me that this would resolve your problem:

```
files[match(1:length(files),rank(-x$size))]
```

Comment: Or possibly `files[order(-x$size)]`?

Answer (score 1):

For me, your code works. You just have to define your new data.frame:

```
x <- x[order(-x$size),]
x
```

Is this, what you expected?

J_F